Index created with Solr 5.3.1 has lucene version 1.2 or negative
I am using Solr 5.3.1 and wish to upgrade this to 6.5
To upgrade this i tried using CheckIndex and IndexUpgrader tool.
Initially i started with lucene-core-6.5.0 and lucene-backward-codec-6.5.0 as mentioned in their official docs. This is throwing org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException. Then i tried using jars with version 5,4,3,2. when using lucene-core-2.9.4 it is throwing org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: Unknown format version: -48132013 How is it possible to have an index with negative lucene version when i am using solr release version 5.3.1

Probable explanation: The index format changed - the value being read isn't the actual index version tag, but some other random value that now lives in that location. In either case - shouldn't Solr 6.5 be able to read Solr 5 indexes by default? iirc you shouldn't have to use the indexupgrader tool at all in that case.

Also observed that this is happening with any new index created
